# How can I sync my OneNote 2013 Notebooks using my own server?

Tags: sync, sharepoint, microsoft-onenote, onedrive

I'm a big fan of OneNote 2013 including the sync function, however I have privacy concerns using Microsoft's Skydrive cloud. Is there a way I can use the same sync comfort with my own server?

OneNote 2013 seems to support Notebooks stored on a Sharepoint, however when trying that out it wasn't possible to specify a certain server address, only my e-mail. Does that mean that the Sharepoint must be hosted by Microsoft as well?

Side condition: I'd like to use the latest clients and apps including Windows Phone...

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I know of is to host your own SharePoint instance.

Older versions of OneNote supported any webDAV server, but newer versions use SharePoint extensions (typical Microsoft).

I'm not aware of any 3rd party Sharepoint compatible server product.

Comment: Thanks - can you say more about the SharePoint extensions? Does this mean that the Sharepoint has to be hosted by Microsoft? Or is it a Microsoft product that can also be hosted by third parties?

Comment: The question was how to make OneNote access the (self-hosted) SharePoint instance since only an email address can be entered ...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I played around a little bit and tried it out:

- With OneNote for Windows and macOS (and the desktop version in any case) you can just open your notebook by supplying a SharePoint URL (pointing to your own server)
- With iOS, the magic is to install the SharePoint app as well. It took some time but after a while the SharePoint account magically appeared in the OneNote app as well. I guess Android works similar.

I am not sure if it works with SharePoint 2013 (or has to be 2016). For the former case, there is the free Foundation version.

For the latter case, see https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/193500/is-there-a-free-version-available-in-sharepoint-2016